# How to prove $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_nz^n+\cdots$, which has infinite items, is an analytic function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

It is easy to prove the following four statements.

(i) If $f$, $g$ are analytic functions and $f^{\prime}$, $g^{\prime}$are continuous then $(f+g)(z)$ is analytic and $(f+g)^\prime(z)=f^\prime(z)+g^\prime(z)$.

(ii) If $f$, $g$ are analytic functions and $f^{\prime}$, $g^{\prime}$are continuous then $(fg)(z)$ is analytic and $(fg)^\prime(z)=f^\prime(z)g(z)+f(z)g^\prime(z)$.

(iii) $f(z)=c$ is analytic and $f^\prime(z)=0$. Here, $c$ is a complex number.

(iv)  $f(z)=z$ is analytic and $f^\prime(z)=1$.

We can use statements (i)-(iv), along with the mathematical induction, to prove that $f(z)=a_{0}+a_{1}z+a_{2}z^{2}+\cdots+a_{n}z^{n}$ is analytic and $f^{\prime}(z)=a_{1}+2a_{2}z+\cdots+na_{n}z^{n-1}$ for all finite n.

But the mathematical induction cannot deal with the situation where $n$ goes to infinite. My question is how to prove $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_nz^n+\cdots$, which has infinite terms,  is an analytic function and $f^{\prime}(z)=a_{1}+2a_{2}z+\cdots+na_{n}z^{n-1}+\cdots$?

Actually, this a question from Ahlfors' Complex Analysis. And I show you the origin of the question below. I have trouble understanding the statement with red line.
[image]

Comment: Any power series is infinitely differentiable and it can be differentiated term by term inside the circle of convergence. In this case, the region of convergence is $\mathbb C$.

Comment: In your statements (i) and (ii), the hypothesis "and $f',g'$ are continuous" is redundant. An [analytic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: See this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/186937/399263

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading Ahlfors's "Complex Analysis". In Chapter2.2 (Elementary Theory of Power Series) you find everything you need. He shows

1. Each power series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nz^n$ has a radius of converge $R \in [0,\infty]$. It may occur that $R = 0$.
2. If $R > 0$, then the series converges absolutely for $\lvert z \rvert < R$. This gives a function $f: D(0,R) = \{ z \in \mathbb C \mid  \lvert z \rvert < R \} \to \mathbb C, f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nz^n$ .
3. On p.39 he introduces the "derived power series" $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty na_nz^{n-1}$ (which we can also write in the form $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n+1)a_{n+1}z^n$). At this point this is just a *formal definition*. Frequently one calls it the *formal derivative* of $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nz^n$.
   He proves that the derived power series has the same radius of converge $R$ and obtains a function $f_1 : D(0,R) \to \mathbb C, f_1(z) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty na_nz^{n-1}$ .
   On p.40 he proves that $f$ is differentiable and $f' = f_1$.

When he introduces the exponential function as the solution of the differential equation
$$f' = f \text{ with initial value } f(0) =1 \tag{$\ast$}$$
he makes the *Ansatz* that $f$ is representable by a power series, i.e.
$$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nz^n$$
on some open disk $D(0,R)$. It is a priori neither clear that differential equation has a solution nor that (if a solution $f$ exists) it is representable by a power series, but under this assumption he derives the necessary condition
$$a_n = 1/n!$$
He then show that the resulting power series has radius of convergence $R = \infty$. By 3. $f$ is differentiable and satisfies $f' = f$. Since $a_0 =1$, one gets $f(0) = 1$.

This justifies the Ansatz.

The aboeve power series is written as
$$e^z = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} z^n .$$

*Remark.*

At this point is not clear that $(*)$ has a *unique solution*. Certainly $e^z$ is the unique power series solution, but this does not exclude a priori that there are also other solutions.

However, later Ahlfors proves that each complex differentiable $f $ can be represented *locally around each point $z_0$ of its domain* as a power series (Taylor's theorem - Theorem 3 on p.177).

This shows that all solutions of $(*)$ agree with $e^z$ on some $D(0,r)$.

Finally, the [identity theorem for analytic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) shows that if the domain $D$ of a solution $f$ is connected, then $f$  is restriction of $e^z$ to $D$. I did not find the identity theorem in Ahlfors's book, but I only took a quick view.