# Are analytic functions with highest convergence radius at a point analytic everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions

This seems to be some elementary point and I have red several questions about it, but I could not have a clarifying answer, so I directly ask myself. I say that a real-valued function $f$ on a real variable (defined on some interval in $\mathbb{R}$) is analytic at $x_0$ if it is $C^\infty$ and such that its Taylor series at $x_0$ converges on some open neighborhood $I_{x_0}$ of $x_0$, and converge to $f$ there.

Now, if we take $y_0$ in such $I_{x_0}$, it seems well known that $f$ is also analytic at $y_0$.

Maybe there is some confusion on the terminology, but my understanding this should mean that there exists $I_{y_0}$ open neighborhood of $y_0$ (presumably $I_{x_0}$ itself) on which the Taylor expansion at $y_0$ (**which is a totally different power series from the Taylor expansion at $x_0$**) converges again pointwise to $f$. Maybe I am missing something elementary, but I do not see any obvious proof of this fact. If someone can help me to clarify, thank you very much.

Comment: A Taylor series $T(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-x_0)^n$ is analytic at *every* interior point of its interval of convergence (or disk of convergence in the complex case). Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? – [how to show that power series is analytic inside the radius of convergence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/186922/42969)

Comment: I do not think this is what I am asking. The function $f$ is said analytic at $x_0$ if its Taylor expansion at $x_0$ converges to f on some interval around $x_0$ (consider real valued functions with real variable only). Take another $y_0$ in this interval. Is it true that the Taylor series of $f$ at $y_0$ also converges to f on the same interval? Why? We know that$$\sum \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n=f(x)$$on some interval $I$ around $x_0$. Take $y_0$ in $I$. Why should it be$$\sum \frac{f^{(n)}(y_0)}{n!}(x-y_0)^n=f(x)$$also for every $x$ in $I$?

Comment: $\sum \frac{f^{(n)}(y_0)}{n!}(x-y_0)^n=f(x)$ holds (at least) in the largest interval around $y_0$ contained in $I$, and that is because $f$ is analytic there (as a Taylor series) and becauses the Taylor series is *unique.*

Comment: The Taylor series at $x_0$ is unique. The one at $y_0$ is another one. Why the second one converges, why it converges to $f$ on $I$? We write another series related to another point, why should it be equal to the one at the previous point on $I$?

Comment: $F(x) = \sum \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$ is analytic at every point in $I$ and equal to $f(x)$. Therefore $$f(x) = F(x) = \sum \frac{F^{(n)}(y_0)}{n!}(x-y_0)^n = \sum \frac{f^{(n)}(y_0)}{n!}(x-y_0)^n$$ around $y_0$.

Comment: @MartinR it seems OP is asking why a convergent power series actually defines an analytic function. But you seem to be just asserting it, not proving it. Granted this is a completely standard statement, but there is some “hard analysis” to be done from scratch.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: That is (IMO) answered in the question that I linked to in my second comment, suggesting as a possible duplicate target. I just hesitate to use my golden dupe-hammer before OP acknowledges that is answers their question.

Comment: I disagree. There, the answer shows that the derivative of a convergent power series is given by such and such convergent power series. I think it’s also a terminology issue because there “analytic” is used to mean “once complex differentiable at every point”, whereas here we’re referring to “for each point in the domain, having a convergent power series in a neighborhood”. These are of course equivalent but this is not trivial. Also in this post the answer mentions that “the radius of convergence is distance to nearest singularity”… which is again a non-trivial fact.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: I am sure that this has been asked and answered before, but I do not have the time right now to search for a better duplicate target.

Comment: Yea Im sure it has (but I’m too lazy to find a dupe). But OP: one source of proof is in Henri Cartan’s complex analysis text, page 37 (you can find it on google preview). This is the “direct” proof of manipulating two different power series, rather than invoking various other equivalences of analytic functions (via Cauchy’s integral formula).

Comment: Thank to peek-a-boo for the reference, I will try to have a look there. Maybe this was answered before, but after a long search I could not find any answer addressing my question yet on MSE. I gave the meaning of what I mean at the beginning, suggesting it may be a terminology problem. Changing the definition to another one at will is answering another question, not this one.

Answer (score 0):

The radius of convergency around any point $z_0$ in the complex plane is the distance to the nearest singular point.

For polynomials there is one singular point at $\infty$ only. Polynomials can be re-expanded around an finite point. Differently from real algebra, $\infty$ is a point by the inversion of neighbourhoods of $(0,\infty)$ at the unit circle $z\to 1/z.$

For meromorphic functions (rationals of polynomials) it is the distance to the nearest pole.

For algebraic functions (defined by solutions of algebraic equations e.eg $ z\to w(z): z=w^2$ , it is   the distance to the nearest branch point or pole.

In general, for series with an inifinite number of nonzero coefficients, it is  the distance to nearest point of divergency from the point of expansion.

For any point $z_1$ inside this circle of convergency of the series in $(z-z_0)^n$ the series can be reorganized in $(z-z_1)^n$, either algebraically or by Taylors formula, convergent in an open neighborhood of however small radius.

It's different radius of convergency will change, maybe randomly, much like the radius of the maximal circle of free view changes during a flight through valleys of the alps at a level of let's say 3000 m.

Classical example:

$$\tan^{-1}(z) = \int\frac{1}{1+z^2} dz = \sum_n \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}z^{2n+1} $$

Its evident by an elementary convergency check at the beginning of a course in complex  theory of functions, that all term by term integrals and derivatives of a power series have the same radius of convergency.

So in this case, there are two poles at $z=\pm i$ and the radius of convergency grows by $\sqrt{1+x_0^2}$ as the distance from a real point of expansion $x_0$

Comment: "For any point $z_1$ inside this circle of convergency of the series in $(z−z_0)^n$ the series can be reorganized in $(z−z_1)^n$, either algebraically or by Taylors formula, convergent in an open neighborhood of however small radius". Do you have a proof or reference to this fact?

Comment: Take the identity theorem of power series (any two power series at the same point for $f(z)$ have identical coefficients). Plus the fact that any point inside the circle of convergency has a positive distance to the nearest  singularity and, by holomorphy of $f(z)$ (complex differentiabilty or power series representation or Cauchy integral representation by boundary values)   in a smaller open disk  has an unique power series with radius of convergency again equal to the distance to the singularity on the circle.